# iterate Json Array with Apache Nifi or Python script

Tags: python, arrays, json, apache-nifi

I have a Json with an Array field that I want to iterate the array and split it into a new row or object for each attribute contained in the Array.

I'm currently using Apache Nifi, but I could also use a python script.

my input data is:

```
{
  "workorder_id" : "99999",
  "properties" : [ {
    "id" : "11",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595398",
      "name" : "action"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string01",
    "nodeValue" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "22",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595419",
      "name" : "Tipo"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string02",
    "nodeValue" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "33",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "44",
      "name" : "Action2"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string02",
    "nodeValue" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "55",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595400",
      "name" : "Action3"
    }
]
}
```

the output can be in Json or csv. for example in csv:
use the same workorder_id as the key

```
workorder_id,id_properties,stringValue_properties
99999,11,string01
99999,22,string02
99999,33,string03
.
.
.
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NiFi

in this sequence:

1. EvaluateJsonPath create attribute from workorder_id (`$.workorder_id`)
2. The output send it to a Split Json on `$.properties.*`
3. The output of splitjson send it to evaluatejson where you will extract the arrays.

   ```
   id = $.id
   propertyType_id = $.propertyType.id
   propertyType_name = $.propertyType.name
   ```

Now each of your flows will carry this attribute :

```
workorder_id,id,propertyType_id,propertyType_name
```

4. use a AttributestoCSV using the this list

   workorder_id,id,propertyType_id,propertyType_name
5. mergecontent
6. putfile (save your csv)

Comment: thanks for the guide, I used EvaluateJsonPath -> SplitJson -> QueryRecord -> ConvertJSONToSQL

Comment: that is actually amore clean approach ! i didnt wanna dive into Records parsers since is a more dificult topic - but that is the optimal approach since split put folws in mem and record parsers dont

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = {
  "workorder_id" : "99999",
  "properties" : [ 
  {
    "id" : "11",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595398",
      "name" : "action"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string01",
    "nodeValue" : float('nan')
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "22",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595419",
      "name" : "Tipo"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string02",
    "nodeValue" : float('nan')
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "33",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "44",
      "name" : "Action2"
    },
    "stringValue" : "string03",
    "nodeValue" : float('nan')
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "55",
    "propertyType" : {
      "id" : "55834595400",
      "name" : "Action3"
      },
    "stringValue" : "string04",
    "nodeValue" : float('nan')
  }
]
}

for item in data['properties']:
    print(data['workorder_id'], item['id'], item['propertyType']['id'], item['propertyType']['name'], item['stringValue'], item['nodeValue'])
    

#99999 11 55834595398 action string01 nan
#99999 22 55834595419 Tipo string02 nan
#99999 33 44 Action2 string03 nan
#99999 55 55834595400 Action3 string04 nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert those nulls to None or some other Python type.

Assuming you switched the nulls to None...

```py
data = {'workorder_id': '99999', 'properties': [{'id': '11', 'propertyType': {'id': '55834595398', 'name': 'action'}, 'stringValue': 'string01', 'nodeValue': None}, {'id': '22', 'propertyType': {'id': '55834595419', 'name': 'Tipo'}, 'stringValue': 'string02', 'nodeValue': None}]}
```

```py
def _handler(prepend: str, record: dict):
    """ relabels keys with a prepended string """
    d = {}
    for key in record.keys():
        new_key = '%s_%s' % (prepend, key)
        d.update({new_key: record[key]})
    return d

def mapper(data: dict):
    """ returns a list of dictionaries. """
    records= []
    properties = data['properties']
    for prop in properties:
        _record = {'workorder_id': data['workorder_id'], }
        
        for prop_key in prop.keys():
            prop_data = {}

            value = prop[prop_key]
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                prop_data.update(_handler(prop_key, value))
            else:
                prop_data.update({prop_key: value})

            _record.update(_handler('property', prop_data))
        records.append(_record)
    return records
```

Output

```
[{'workorder_id': '99999',
  'property_id': '11',
  'property_propertyType_id': '55834595398',
  'property_propertyType_name': 'action',
  'property_stringValue': 'string01',
  'property_nodeValue': None},
 {'workorder_id': '99999',
  'property_id': '22',
  'property_propertyType_id': '55834595419',
  'property_propertyType_name': 'Tipo',
  'property_stringValue': 'string02',
  'property_nodeValue': None}]
```